# How to detect changes of an Entity without using POCO files

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, entity-framework-4

I need to detect if my entity object is dirty. I am not using POCO files. I simply have a model class and i am using the entity framework 4.0.

I have a Comment field in the user input form and i need to find if the user has made some changes to the comment. for that i am using the following method:

```
public bool DetectChanges()
    {
        return (insurableRiskEntities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted).Any());
    }
```

For some reason it is not working correctly. It is returning false, even if i enter the Comment is changed.

Any suggestions, as to what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use logical operators instead of binary ones.

`EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted` means, an object that has all 3 states set. You want to use `EntityState.Added || EntityState.Modified || EntityState.Deleted` to check if any on of them is set